# Не распознает шрифт в Safaris

Tags: html, google-chrome, iphone, safari

Проблема в том, что проверяя свою верстку на iPhone, шрифты различаются с Android и Windows. Как это исправить?

Это с iPhone
[image: Это safari]

Это с Android
[image: Это Chrome]

Comment: а что за шрифт, какой формат шрифта и как Вы его подключаете?

Comment: @humster_spb шрифт "Segoe UI", подключил через font-family и ничего более

Comment: если верить http://iosfonts.com/ safari просто не поддерживает такой шрифт

Comment: @humster_spb и как с этим быть? искать подходящий шрифт, который поддерживает safari. Но проблема еще в том, что не только в safari такой шрифт, но и во всех браузерах iPhone

Comment: ну да, значит искать какой-то другой. и, как минимум, в font-family прописать свойство sans-serif, чтоб хотя бы засечек не было

Comment: @humster_spb спасибо